# How to skip undo changes made by a certain function?

Tags: undo

The goal is to prevent the possibility of undoing some automatic text additions into buffer.

So far I tried to solve it by:

```lisp
    (defun skip-undo (orig-fun)
      (let ((buffer-undo-list t))
        (apply orig-fun nil)))
    
    (advice-add 'fun-that-adds-some-text :around #'skip-undo)
```

It works. But when `fun-that-adds-some-text` adds some text, all positions after that addition in the buffer will be affected. And all of the undos after this position will be broken.

How could it be solved?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Short of horribly abusing the undo-in-region functionality, I don't know how you'd approach that.  Why do you want to?  What is the nature of the text?

Comment: In certain cases, it is necessary to add HASH checksums with the TIMESTAMP of the entry body to the PROPERTY drawer. And then it would be better not to accidentally undo it.

Comment: I guess you're talking about org-mode.  I'd suggest that it's preferable not to accidentally undo *anything* that you didn't *mean* to undo, so I don't understand why this is different to any other change.  My only suggestion is that you additionally write the information to a log file that you're not editing, and that way you have a backup record which isn't subject to accidental keystrokes.  I have no solution for what you're actually asking for, though.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was easier than I thought. With the following solution, all changes can be sequentially restored with undo, except those made by `fun-that-adds-some-text`.

```lisp
(defun skip-undo (orig-fun &rest args)
  (undo-boundary)
  (apply orig-fun args)
  (setq buffer-undo-list (memq nil buffer-undo-list)))
    
(advice-add 'fun-that-adds-some-text :around #'skip-undo)
```